# ERROR: ROWS must be positive

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin-4

Why the error when I run the below in pgAdmin 4 query editor?  I copied the create statement in one database and trying to move to a new server.

So I right clicked the function in pgAdmin and selected from the menu Scripts --> CREATE Script the generate the below code.  Copied and executed into a new database.

```
-- FUNCTION: public.osmtrip_format(bigint, numeric, numeric)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.osmtrip_format(bigint, numeric, numeric);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.osmtrip_format(
    num bigint,
    length numeric,
    tolerance numeric)
RETURNS bigint
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100
    IMMUTABLE 
    ROWS 0
AS $BODY$

    SELECT
        CASE WHEN $1=0 OR $2<=0.7*$3 THEN NULL ELSE $1 END;

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.osmtrip_format(bigint, numeric, numeric)
    OWNER TO gis;

ERROR:  ROWS must be positive
SQL state: 22023
```

Comment: Looks like a pgAdmin 4 bug. `ROWS 0` is invalid

Comment: how do I modify?

Comment: Replace it with `ROWS 1` before running it

Comment: If I use ROWS 1: ERROR:  ROWS is not applicable when function does not return a set
    SQL state: 22023

Comment: Then remove it completely

Comment: What @a_horse_with_no_name said. From the docs, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html : *"**result_rows**
    A positive number giving the estimated number of rows that the planner should expect the function to return. **This is only allowed when the function is declared to return a set.** The default assumption is 1000 rows."*

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ: There is no better answer. If you don't want to add this as answer,  the question should be closed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter done.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation about [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html):

> **`result_rows`**
>   A **positive** number giving the estimated number of rows that the planner should expect the function to return. **This is only allowed when the function is declared to return a set.** The default assumption is 1000 rows."

`ROWS 0` is not allowed even in those functions (should be positive).

Since the function is not returning a set, you need to remove that `ROWS n`.